# How can I easily replace one control for another with the same name in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The first problem is that in `form1` top I have:

```
ListViewNF lvnf;
```

The `ListViewNF` is a class in `form1`:

```
class ListViewNF : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
        {
            public ListViewNF()
            {
                //Activate double buffering
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

                //Enable the OnNotifyMessage event so we get a chance to filter out 
                // Windows messages before they get to the form's WndProc
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
            }

            protected override void OnNotifyMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                if (m.Msg != 0x14)
                {
                    base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
                }
            }
        }
```

Then in the form1 constructor I'm making instance for the `lvnf` variable set the size, location and add this control `lvnf` to the `form1` controls.
Then in my program I'm using the `lvnf` in some places.

But now I want to make a new `UserControl` call it `lvnf` so when I drag the `UserControl` from the toolbox to the `form1` designer it will replace the `lvnf` I created.

The first problem is once I delete the line:

```
ListViewNF lvnf;
```

I'm getting many errors and can't see the form1 designer I'm getting an error since `lvnf` not exist.

If I don't delete it and drag the new `UserControl` it will give the new control another name and I want it to be `lvnf`. I don't want to change anything in my run time code related to the `lvnf` only the control in the designer.

This is the code of the `UserControl`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Pop3_Emails
{
    public partial class ListViewNF : UserControl
    {
        public ListViewNF()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
        }
    }
}
```

Should I make all the events of the `lvnf` to move them to the `UserControl` code? Or leave them all on `form1`?

The main problem is how to use the `UserControl` as `lvnf`.
Also I need to use the code in the class `ListViewNF`.

What a mess. In general what I want to do is to make the `lvnf` the `ListViewNF` a control in the `form1` designer instead a control in the run time code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Drag the new `UserControl` onto the form, under a different name (`x` for example)
2. Rename the `lvnf` to `x`, asking Visual Studio to update all references. Ignore the warning that the name already exists, and the project won't compile.
3. Remove the `ListViewNF x` declaration (now the project should compile again).
4. Rename `x` back to `lvnf`, also updating all references.